# How to hook into "visiting the website"?

Tags: 7, rules, nodes

My main problem is very similar to [How to grant userpoints to users who perform a login 5 days consecutively?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/35484/how-to-grant-userpoints-to-users-who-perform-a-login-5-days-consecutively). As Mike correctly notices in [his answer](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/35509/16550) on that question, his solution will not work for users who leave their browser logged in. Therefore, I do not want to hook into a login, but into "visiting the website" (i.e. accessing *any* page).

I am fine with both Rules and custom code. In the first case, which Rules event can I use? For performance reasons, it is in both cases desirable that the hooking takes place as few times as possible (in the best case once a day per visiting user). Is restricting the visited page to a particular one, say, the homepage the only way to achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) Event "***Drupal is initializing***" (within "System") for sure will do the job:

- It doesn't depend on login (can be used for any role).
- It applies to any path (a node, a view, etc).

Should you want to do so, you can also add any desired Rules Conditions (eg to only consider selected paths, eventually using RegEx expression also).

#### Make it right before you make it better

I'm not sure this is the *only* way your question can be answered, but I do know that this Rules Event (*Drupal is initializing*) *will* do what you're asking for, which is to **hook into "visiting the website" (i.e. visiting *any* page)** (as in your question).

But, using this Rules Event also comes with a price: it will case this rule to be triggered on every page request (which is a pretty similar to your *visiting any page*). However, if this price is too high, maybe you want to consider any (or all?) of these compromises:

- Add Rules Conditions such as "only for users with selected roles" (eg: authenticated, so that for Anonymous users the Rules Actions are not triggered).
- Instead of **any** page, you only take into consideration something like "viewing content" (for which you know there are less expensive Rules Events available).

Comment: Thank you Pierre, that will certainly do. But I am a bit worried that *Drupal is initializing* is a bit expensive. I mean, the Rule will run on every page request, although it should actually be fired only once per day per visiting user. Are you sure this is the only way?

Comment: Oh, that is your call. I would have deleted it, since it does not really add much value to me; I suppose anyone can find the correct event. But if my edit was rejected, I assume that there must be a good reason for it.

Comment: No problem at all! Your answer is still the correct one and that is what counts. I will delete my comments once you have read this one.